# I'd like to do a plain substring match with shell scripts

Tags: shell

I'd like know how to do a plain substring match in a shell script.

For example, if I have

```
STRING1="http://127.0.0.1/"
STRING2="http://127101011/"
SUBSTRING="127.0.0.1"
```

I want SUBSTRING to match STRING1 but not STRING2. It's like java.lang.String.indexOf(String).

I guess the problem can also be fixed by properly escaping the content of SUBSTRING, too, but I can't seem to figure out how to.

Thank you,
wbkang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
STRING1="http://127.0.0.1/"
STRING2="http://127101011/"
SUBSTRING="127.0.0.1"
for string in "$STRING1" "$STRING2"
do
    case "$string" in
    (*$SUBSTRING*) echo "$string matches";;
    (*)            echo "$string does not match";;
    esac
done
```

The '`(*)`' notation in the `case` works in Korn shell and Bash; it won't work in the original Bourne shell - that requires no leading '`(`'.

Alternatively, the `expr` command can be used - that is another classic (and POSIX) command that is probably made obsolete by some of the features in more modern shells.

Comment: Hahaha brilliant solution. I'll make a little function out of that. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the leading `(`'s. They're at best useless (in nonstandard shells) and at worst incorrect.

Comment: For the record, you don't need to use a case statement, an if will do as well: `if [[ *$needle* == $haystack ]]; then echo found; else echo not found; fi`

Answer (score 4):

You can find a script for this here:

http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html

```
fnmatch () { case "$2" in $1) return 0 ;; *) return 1 ;; esac ; }
```

Or, a slightly more efficient version might be:

```
fnmatch () { case "$2" in $1) return 0 ;; esac ; return 1 ; }
```

Then use it as:

```
if fnmatch "$SUBSTRING" "$STRING1" ; then ...
```

Note that `*`, `?`, and brackets `[]` will be treated as special according to `glob`/`fnmatch` pattern rules (not regex).

Comment: Note that this won't work with the original example, as fnmatch expects SUBSTRING to contain the wildcard characters as well. The correct usage for the given SUBSTRING is `fnmatch "*$SUBSTRING*" "$STRING1"`. Other than that, +1 for correct syntax and optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function is_matching() {
    if [[ `echo "$1" | grep "$2"` != "" ]]; then return 1; fi
    return 0;
}

is_matching "abcd" "bc"
echo $?
is_matching "abcd" "XX"
echo $?
```

Running that script:

```
$ ./test
1
0
```

If you want to do it without forking grep, read this link -> [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: OP wanted **non-regex** matching.